# How do you migrate agents using the Jade framework in Java?

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence, agents-jade, jade4j

Is there anyone who knows of a method to migrate agent between containers in Jade framework without using the `doMove()` function of the agent class?

Answer (score 0):

In the RMS gui, select migrate.

[image]

Another option is requesting that an(other) agent be moved via the AMS. See chapter 6.4.5 of the book.
[image]
F. L. Bellifemine, G. Caire, and D. Greenwood, Developing Multi-Agent Systems with JADE. Wiley.